the hadith in which the one who recites 1000 verses gets huge rewards.. is that reward jannah tul firdous?And can i read it once or is it daily?
I read a hadith in which the prophet pbuh said:  “Whoever stands to pray with ten verses will never be recorded among the negligent. Whoever stands with a hundred verses will recorded among those devoutly obedient to Allah. Whoever stands with a thousand verses will be recorded among those with tremendous rewards.”
Is the reward mentioned here”jannat tul firdous?” And can i read these 1000 verses once a year or once a month or once in my life or should i read them daily since i have to go to school and i have to sleep early
Jazak Allah

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please clarify: What is the source of this hadith? Is your quote an exact quote of a known translation or paraphrased?
